# How to securely store chat audio message files in the storage bucket?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-s3, row-level-security

For my project, I am using supabase which uses postgres for database and s3 for storage.

Here are the requirements that I want to achieve:

1. I want to have one to one and group chat messaging "rooms".
2. User can prerecord a audio message such as "intro to chat" message which they could reuse many times.
3. Audio messages should only be accessed either by a creator or a member of a particular chat.

At the moment I have a single private storage bucket called **user-content**.

I don't know how to secure access to the audio files, but for example this rule:

```
((bucket_id = 'user-content'::text) AND ((auth.uid())::text = (storage.foldername(name))[1]))
```

How would I secure individual audio files so that only authorised users would be able to access it?

Here is my SQL schema at the moment:

```
// mesages
    id serial,
    sender_id uuid null,
    chat_id integer null,
    text text not null,
    created_at timestamp
// notifications

    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    created_at timestamp with time zone null default now(),
    message_id integer null,
    is_read boolean not null default false,
    sender_id uuid null,
    recipient_id uuid null,
    chat_id bigint null,

// attachments

    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    message_id integer null,
    attachment_type text null,
    url text null,
    file_name text null,
    file_size double precision null,
    blurhash text null,
```

Would I have to create RLS rules which would involve checking my postgres tables to determine if specific user has access to that audio file?